What are the Error Reduction Factors for Shor’s EC, Knill’s Gadget, Steane’s Gadget, and Flag Gadgets?
Similar to how cat state gadgets make the number of errors $p$ into $(1-p)^m$ what do the aforementioned gadgets do? If not the error reduction, what is the threshold?
Even if it is a link to a research paper, all help is incredibly helpful!!!

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
